# Publishing Problems

Tags: .net, web-config, publishing, remote-debugging

I have an ASP.NET web project that works perfectly on my computer. However, when I publish to the remote server, it crashes. The only page I see is the main startup page. If I click on any link I get an error page. The error page tells me that it can't tell me what the error is (for security reasons), and that I should set customError mode="off" in my web.config file, which I did. However, it still won't show me any of the error details. Can someone explain to me how I can figure out what the error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is case sensitive, so first make sure CustomError Mode="Off" not "off".

Next, are you running the application within a subdirectory of another asp.net site? If so, check to make sure that site has custom errors turned off.

Still no luck? What webserver are you using, IIS6 or 7? Did you restart the application or app pool after making the config changes (usually should happen automatically)? Are other .net applications running on the same server?